# My character go nuts when i apply automatic weight

Tags: weight-painting, rigify

So i'm trying multiple kind of rigging for my character and rn i'm trying rigify.
i'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAhbO7U1ID8&ab_channel=THELUWIZART

But at the moment where he apply automatic weight, i go from this :

[image]

To This :

[image]

I've tried working manualy on the weighting but it's way too long and i think there might be a simplier way, i just can't find it.

Here's the file https://pasteall.org/blend/958a1217115849cca18223595bb6dd40

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope a *Stretch To* constraint expert will find the smart way to fix your problem but from what I understand:

If you activate this armature layer you'll see some highly stretched bones:

[image]

These bones have a *Stretch To* constraint. You've probably scaled and applied the scale of your armature. This operation has stretched these bones, as the constraints have kept the same *Original Length* value but now the scale is not the same:

[image]

To bring the bones back to their good length you need to multiply the *Original Length* value by the previous armature scale, but you may not have it. Another way to fix it is to take note of the *Target* of the constraint, remove the constraint, then create a new one, and type the same *Target*, it will bring back the good *Original Length* value. If all your stretch bones have the same length then you could simply type this value in all your constraints instead of removing them.

If you have a previous version of your armature and character, you could avoid to apply the scale, or parent the armature to an empty and scale the empty itself, not the armature.

Comment: Thanks to you explaining the bones we're stretched because i scaled them, i restarted the project and when i spawned the armature instead of scaling it up, i scaled my character's model down and now it works perfectly