# Model Stretching

Tags: modeling, rendering, pose-mode

Tried to pose this model for a cutscene. It appeared like this, I don't know what I hit or what caused it, but it won't stretch back or take up the poses I set up for it.[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe this will answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260687/my-character-go-nuts-when-i-apply-automatic-weight/260694#260694

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything, but when I delete the rig, it goes back to normal but now I can't pose it.

Comment: But did you have some Stretch To constraint for some of your bones?

Comment: No, I checked the other models too and they don't have any either.

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can see what is the problem (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/